# Yii: Edit search feature in _search.php file

Tags: php, search, yii, cgridview

I want to add one **extra field** which is **not part of model** file.
I want to add a textbox(user can type anthing in it) which should be matched with all the other values in **CGridview** and only matching ones should be displayed.
But I cant understand how _search form provides value to CGridview.
How can I **feed the CGridview widget** with the value of this new textbox.
(This field is not part of model so default search functionality  can not be used for it)

Comment: Can u post some code that u have tried ??

Answer (score 0):

Create a property with your custom field, create a method that uses the property to build a query that returns the records.

```
class Model extends CActiveRecord {

    public $globalSearch;

       public globalSearch()
       {
           $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
           // Conditions follow
           ...
           // Return models
           return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
               ));
       }
 }

 // Controller (or perhaps view if using a widget)

 $model = new Model;
 $model->globalSearch = 'parameter'

 $this->render('view', array('model'=>$model->globalSearch()));
```